# How can I tell Spring Data REST to return an error code on an invalid endpoint?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

We had an error recently where were were trying to disassociate two entities in a Spring Boot application with a DELETE, but we were hitting the wrong endpoint e.g. `/api/school/student` rather than `/api/student/school/`. As Student is the owning entity here, hitting the first endpoint did nothing, but still returned a 204 status code, which tricked us into thinking it was ok. Is there a way we could make it return a 4xx code instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a controller method for that endpoint which simply returns 4xx.

Or you can modify your schema in a way that a many-to-many relationship could be managed from both side.

Comment: I considered that but the main issue is that this error could be in any number of places that we don't know about, and this won't help until we find where those errors are.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that have a controller which takes all unresolved url and returns a result with no content. Something in your code like:

```
@GetMapping("/**") or @GetMapping("/api/**")
```

remove it and you will get the 404 error message.

Comment: We don't have a controller like that, we're using Spring Data REST/JPA to 'generate' endpoints to create entities. The issue is that some of these generated endpoints don't actually work, but still return a 204, so are sometimes tricky to detect.